# Can a nonzero win-win situation appear in a purely competitive 2 players game?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, game-theory, quantum-information

I thought using quantum theory to achieve that goal, namely that the distinction between players is artificial and in fact each player is a superposition of players given in the data, since they normally have some properties in common.

This means that the matrix of payoffs with probabilities of strategies were :

$$\begin{array}[cccc] & A & & p_3& p_4\\& B & q_3&q_4\\p_1&q_1&(1,-1)&(-1,1)\\p_2&q_2&(-1,1)&(1,-1)\end{array}$$

The conditions are $$\sum_{i=1}^4 p_i=\sum_{i=1}^4 q_i=1$$
And $$\sum_{i=n}^{n+1}p_i+q_i=1,n=1,3$$

Those equations are dependent leaving only 3 left.

Let say player A corresponds to mixing coefficients p and B to q.
The problem arises when computing gains. Is it meaningful to say player A is a superposition with probability p1+p2 of 1 and so :

$$G_A=(p_1+p_2)G_{1,A}+(p_3+p_4)G_{2,A}$$

With $$G_{1,A}=-G_{2,A}$$ ?

In fact it's a question of interpretation of the players 1/2 becoming A/B which are a superposition of the formers. It's like this could happen in some sense if the we shall consider the 2 players as a whole. But this makes no sense in practice.

Comment: Does the prisoner's dilemma not qualify?

Comment: Pure competition means the sum is zero for each pure strategy choice : $$\begin{array}[cc](g_{11},-g_{11}) &(g_{12},-g_{12})\\(g_{21},-g_{21})&(g_{22},-g_{22})\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

A pure competition game is when players have exactly opposite interests. This means there can be only $2$ players as it is not possible to have exactly opposite interests if the number of players is greater than $2$.

So, this is either a zero-sum game or a constant-sum game with $2$ players.

If it is a constant sum game, you can have a win-win. Example: two competitors fighting for declaring their technology as a standard. This is a constant-sum game and the competitors both gain if they agree on a standard and their winnings is greater than any other opposing strategy they could have individually followed.

In a zero-sum game, one of them wins and the other loses or both of them lose.

Comment: The problem here boils down to find stationary points of : $Ga=(p1+p2-p3-p4)(p1-p2)(p3-p4)$. It comes out that there are nonzero maxima at the boundary, giving that there exist nonzero equilibria (=equal win for A and B).